# How to log newly instantiated member status changes in a replica set

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to benchmark when a new mongo replica member

1. first communicates to my replica set.
2. change state from STARTUP2 -> RECOVERY
3. change state from RECOVERING -> SECONDARY

I'm specifically looking for exact duration on how long it took for the replica to run it's initial sync or the timestamps to parse such actions by a new member.

Is there a log that will give me this information?

I'm currently using the following script in mongo shell.

```
MAXSCRIPT_RUN_ITERATIONS = 1800 // approximately 30 minutes

for (var i = 0; i < MAXSCRIPT_RUN_ITERATIONS; i++) {
  sleep(1000);
  var currentdate = new Date();
  var datetime = new Date().toLocaleString();
  var rsStatus = rs.status()
  var members = rsStatus.members
  // Change this index depending on the # of members in your set
  var resyncmember = members[0]
  var resyncMemberState = resyncmember.stateStr
  print("--------------")
  print("Member Count: " + members.length + " " + datetime)
  for (var n = 0; n < members.length; n++){
    var member = members[n]
    print("HOST: " + member.name  + " State: " + member.stateStr)
  }
  if (resyncMemberState == "SECONDARY"){
    print("########################")
    var currentdate = new Date();
    print("resyncMember finished: " + datetime)
    print("########################")
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic for StackOverflow as this is not a programming based question. Ask on [dbastackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead, which exists for all your database configuration and administration questions and needs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't state what version you're running on, so I'll give information about 3.0 (3.2) should be the same.

Look through your mongodb log for entries like the following:

```
2016-02-25T14:59:43.684+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync drop all databases
2016-02-25T14:59:43.684+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync clone all databases
2016-02-25T14:59:43.688+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync cloning db: admin
2016-02-25T14:59:43.833+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync cloning db: db1
2016-02-26T10:31:33.763+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync cloning db: test
2016-02-26T11:27:48.480+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync data copy, starting syncup
2016-02-26T11:27:48.481+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] oplog sync 1 of 3
2016-02-26T11:27:49.043+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: xxxxxxxxxx:27017
2016-02-26T11:27:49.059+0000 I REPL     [SyncSourceFeedback] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to xxxxxxxxxx:27017
2016-02-26T11:30:05.649+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] oplog sync 2 of 3
2016-02-26T11:30:05.657+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync building indexes
2016-02-26T11:30:05.657+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync cloning indexes for : admin
2016-02-26T11:30:05.760+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync cloning indexes for : db1
2016-02-26T11:43:37.262+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync cloning indexes for : test
2016-02-26T11:43:48.271+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] oplog sync 3 of 3
2016-02-26T11:43:48.319+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync finishing up
2016-02-26T11:43:48.319+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] replSet set minValid=56d03a74:1
2016-02-26T11:43:48.321+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync done
2016-02-26T11:43:48.332+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to RECOVERING
2016-02-26T11:43:48.348+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to SECONDARY
```

As you can see, you see information for each stage of the initial sync process, and when the transition to a **SECONDARY** node occurs. You will see more lines than this, but I've cut down to show what you should look for.

You can view this realtime with a command similar to the following if you're on a Linux or Mac machine (make sure to run this before adding the new node or you might miss some lines)

```
tail -f /path/to/mongodb.log | grep REPL
```

This will watch your log file as entries are being added and only display the lines with the string REPL in it. Remember to kill the `tail` command once you've gotten the information you need.